# How to find position of a word in a div (y coordinate)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a lot of text within a `DIV`. I would like to be able to search it on a string using perhaps a PHP regex then find the `y` position of that text that is searched on so I can place an image next to it.

I believe this would be the best way of doing it, I am unsure. However, I can't figure out how to determine how many pixels from the top of the screen that line is. Any recommendations?

Comment: @user1524441 did none of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

@user1524441 not sure if this what you mean but from what I understand you want to add an image next to a specific search term, if this is the case you can use the following approach assuming you are using jquery:

```
var search = "Robin";
var text = $('.content').text();
$('.content').html(text.replace(search,'<span class="search-term" style="font-weight:bold;">' + search + '</span>'));
$('.search-term').before('<img src="url/goes/here" alt="" title=""/>');
```

here is a jsfiddle displaying how it works http://jsfiddle.net/6YsfB/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `substring` and `indexOf`

```
var serch = "Robin"
var text = "hi my name is Robin, what you so talk? I'm god";

document.write(text.substring(text.indexOf(serch),text.indexOf(serch)+(serch).length));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5bejQ/1/

Comment: Where's the code that adds the image to highlight the words? I think you have misunderstood the question...

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing the search on the server, you could output the found text wrapped in <span> tags with a certain CSS class:

Here is some text with the <span class = "highlighted">text of interest</span> highlighted.

Then you could use the CSS "content" property (http://css-tricks.com/css-content/) in conjunction with the :before or :after pseudo-classes to show an image before or after the highlighted text.